# Директивы mod_access

Tags: php, .htaccess

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли следующее правило записать при помощи директив `mod_access`?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^66\.249\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: можно с использованием mod_access + mod_setenvif